# Using wildcards with update statements

Tags: mysql

I would like to update specific strings in a table, but the strings themselves have variables.  So,

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=examplevideo
```

"examplevideo" is a variable string that I would like to preserve for the replacement string in

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/examplevideo"></iframe>
```

Is there a way to do this in one update statement?

So, the table looks like this;

```
 select messageid,userid, subject, message  from feed_messages;
+-----------+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| messageid | userid | subject     | message                                                            |
+-----------+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        74 |     67 | Test        | message                                                            |
|        75 |     67 | Test        | message                                                            |
|        77 |     67 | Test        | message                                                            |
|        78 |     67 | Test        | message                                                            |
|        90 |     70 | How are ya? | message                                                            |
|       106 |     67 | Test        | message                                                            |
|       107 |     67 | Test        | message                                                            |
|       117 |     67 | Test post   | Here's a test post;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWqD7GyJBVM |
+-----------+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to keep everything in the message field for messageid 117 but modify the link so that it the video will be embeded when it posts.

Comment: Mysql ?? Guess you think of some dom manipulation, eg javascript?

Comment: Could you show us the code you have so far? Right now, it's not even clear what you're trying to do, let alone where you got stuck doing it.

Comment: I've updated the original question with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL's native `REGEXP` expression, even when combined with `REPLACE()`, isn't enough to accomplish what you want on its own.

In pure MySQL, this wouldn't be easy to do unless you use [this set of user-defined functions (UDFs) for MySQL](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp) that implement advanced regular expression functionality for MySQL statements, like group capturing (which is what you need).

If you're capable of installing those UIDs, then you can use the following:

```
UPDATE `feed_messages` SET
  `message` = REGEXP_REPLACE(
    `message`,
    'https?://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11})[a-zA-Z0-9-_%&=]*',
    '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1"></iframe>')
WHERE
  `message` REGEXP 'youtube\.com/watch\?v=[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11}';
```

If you aren't capable of using those UDFs, then this will pretty much have to be accomplished outside of the database. For example, in PHP:

```
$query = 'SELECT `messageid`,`userid`,`subject`,`message` FROM `feed_messages`';
$msgs = $mysqli->query($query);
while ($row = $msgs->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo preg_replace(
    $row['message'],
    '/https?://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11})[a-zA-Z0-9-_%&=]*/im',
    '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1"></iframe>')
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could use SUBSTRING_INDEX to determine the position of the string 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' and do it again to get the position of the next blank space after that. With these two positions you could extract the video Id and combine  Leonid's replacement and CONCAT to insert opening and closing iframe tags.

Comment: Okay, so select substring_index('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','.',3); gets the first piece, but how do I use it to find the first space after the end of the link?